Is there a difference between ほっぺ and 頬?
They both mean "cheek" but is one more casual or technical than the other or can you use both interchangeably?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ほっぺ says "childish", while https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/ほっぺ says "ほっぺたの幼児語".

ほっぺ is colloquial and often associated with childlike speech or cute expressions. While adults may use it casually among friends or family members, it's avoided in formal situations. 頬 is a neutral to formal word for the same part.
